# How to schedule a job to run 10 sec later in quartz.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I have a scheduled job that will fire every 1 minute, how can I schedule a job to run 10 sec later when added to scheduler?

```
var jobKey = new JobKey("firstJob", "jobGroup");

var firstJob = JobBuilder.Create<MatchJob>()
    .WithIdentity("firstJob")
    //.SetJobData()
    .WithIdentity(jobKey)
    .Build();

var firstTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("firstTrigger")
    .StartNow()
    //.StartAt(DateTime.Today.Hour)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

AddJobToScheduler(firstJob, firstTrigger);
```

Comment: your question seems a bit unclear, do you mean that you want a job that trigger 10 seconds after your job that is triggered every minute. Or do you want a job that is triggered 10 seconds after it is added?

Comment: i have a job will fire every minute but, i want to add another job to scheduler to run 10 sec later after added to scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it with a cron-expression looking something like this: `10 0/1 * * * ? *`? This would fire with one minute intervals but 10 seconds after your other job.

To add a cron-expression simply use `.WithCronSchedule("10 0/1 * * * ? *")` on your trigger.

The cron expression for your current job would be `0 0/1 * * * ? *`. For a good tutorial on cron-expressions check [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) out!

**Edit**

If what you want is a job that is fired 10 seconds after its added to scheduler you could just do `.StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10))`

Comment: thank you @Simon Karlsson,all thing i understand of your answer is "create a job fire after 10 second when another job fired" ,but i want a job that fire 10 sec after added to scheduler saperatly other jobs.

Comment: @Edalat You want the job to just fire once after it has been added to the scheduler?

Comment: thank you @Simon Karlsson my problem is solved before i use StartAt() method in this case .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(10,IntervalUnit.Second)) when application start it's fire, not 10 sec later...